class returning garbage strings in C++ 1.0
As the title says, my class is returning garbage strings and I can't figure out where the problem is.  Note that this code is early C++ and I don't have access to namespaces (i.e. no std::string).
I did search the Q&A before posting, but most of the other Qs are assuming a more modern implementation of the language.
class definition file:
#ifndef SOFTWARE_HPP
#define SOFTWARE_HPP 1

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

class Software
{
    char* name;

    public:
    Software( void );
    Software( const Software& software );
    Software( const char* Name );
    ~Software( void );

    Software& operator=( const Software& software );

    void Name( const char* Name );
    char* Name( void ) const;
};

void GetSoftware( Software** software, const unsigned short ArraySize );

#endif

Class implementation file:
#include "software.hpp"

const unsigned short max_software_name = 21;

Software::Software( void )
{
    name = new char[max_software_name + 1];

    name[0] = NULL;
}

Software::Software( const Software& software )
{
    name = new char[strlen( software.Name() ) + 1];

    strncpy( name, software.Name(), max_software_name );
}

Software::Software( const char* Name )
{
    name = new char[max_software_name + 1];

    strncpy( name, Name, max_software_name );
}

Software::~Software( void )
{
    delete[] name;
}

Software& Software::operator=( const Software& software )
{
    name = new char[strlen( software.Name() ) + 1];

    strncpy( name, software.Name(), max_software_name );

    return *this;
}

void Software::Name( const char* Name )
{
    if ( strlen( Name ) < max_software_name ) {
        strncpy( name, Name, max_software_name );
    }
}

char* Software::Name( void ) const
{
    return name;
}

void GetSoftware( Software** software, const unsigned short ArraySize )
{
    for ( short i = 0; i < ArraySize; ++i ) {
        software[i] = new Software( "SoftwareName" );
    }
}

Then in my main program:
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "software.hpp"

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    Software* software[16] = { NULL };
    GetSoftware( software, 16 );

    for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof( software ) / sizeof( software[0] ); ++i ) {
        printf( "Software %s", software[i]->Name() );
    }
}

If I printf the Software::Name from the implementation file, the characters are fine. But when I try to output the string from the main() function, I get a bunch of garbage characters.
One interesting note is that if I run my application from my Windows NT development machine, the characters print out fine, but when run under true DOS is when I get the garbles.
This is a medium memory model project, btw.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

void GetSoftware( Software* (&software)[], const unsigned short ArraySize ); -- Which book or (good) tutorial shows a function declaration looking anything like this?  Even pre-1998 C++ code, you won't find anything looking like this in any book I know of.  Also, do not tag C, as your code is clearly C++, even if it's pre-standard C++.

void GetSoftware( Software* (&software)[], const unsigned short ArraySize ) should be void GetSoftware( Software *software[], const unsigned short ArraySize ) if I am not mistaken.

Also, int main() { Software s("abc123"); Software s2 = s; } -- you have more issues other than garbage strings.  That simple code has a double-free error.

What compiler are you using? I'd like to try that out myself just for fun.

Note that this code is C with Classes -- It is C++ without any post 1998 standard library usage.  Note that the code compiles with the latest version of g++.

"my array of objects by reference" -- You have an array of pointers, not of objects. But aside from that, why an array? Does the problem not reproduce if you simplify to a single object, dropping the array?

@TedLyngmo Symantec C++ 7.2.

"C with classes" was the predecessor to C++, way before C++98. "The C++ Programming Language" was published in 1985, and C++98 was based on that; C with classes was pretty much a dead letter at that point. Certainly by 1990, when Borland released Turbo C++ 1.0, there was no longer any interest in C with classes; it was all C++.

@CharlieDobson -- to be clear, Symantec C++ 7.2 (1995) was C++, not C with classes. It was pre-C++98 spec, sure, but the standard was in process at the time, and vendors were targeting C++, not C with classes.

I don't think Walter Bright would like his compiler to be called a "C" compiler.  Symantec C++ 7.2, which I used to have 25 years ago, was a C++ compiler that rivaled Borland C++ and Visual C++ at that time.

This: void GetSoftware( Software** software, const unsigned short ArraySize ) is much more understandable than this: void GetSoftware( Software* (&software)[], const unsigned short ArraySize ).

@CPlus I just changed void GetSoftware( Software* (&software)[], const unsigned short ArraySize ); to void GetSoftware( Software *software[], const unsigned short ArraySize ); per your suggestion, but the result is the same.

@PaulMcKenzie what is a double-free error?

@CharlieDobson -- Run your code (actually, the simple main I posted).  Your code may crash on exit.  A double-free error means that you are calling delete [] on the same pointer value two or more times.  Your Software class failed to implement the rule of 3.  Note, the rule of 3 existed even in the pre-standard C++ days.  Go to the Managing resources section of that page, and you will see a class that has similar issues to yours.

Side note: names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_MAX_SOFTWARE_NAME) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation; don't use them in your code.

I've updated the title and dropped the C with Classes phrasing.  Thanks all!

You use new, delete and const, thus it's not C with classes, these keywords are since C++ 1st edition (1985).

@CharlieDobson Double free means you accidentally freed/deleted something twice, when you should only do so once.

"(i.e. no std::string)." So start by creating your own string class.

@PaulMcKenzie thanks for pointing me in that direction for the rule of 3.  What is your recommendation regarding creating destructors, copy constructors, and copy assignment operators, specifically in my case?  Should I not use them?  Or should I make it habit to start implementing all 3 in my classes?

You could create a smart pointer yourself if none exists. One question is why you use a pointer at all since all your strings have the same length. Why not just make the array a normal member variable?

@TedLyngmo Good question.  I would rather new and strlen the pointer but I don't know best practice on initializing a pointer in a class on the default constructor when no length has been specified for the member variable.

@CharlieDobson -- How can you avoid not using them, especially the destructor?  Look at the harm a simple 2 line main program can cause.  Thus you need to implement the copy-assignment operators and destructors, regardless if your code will "use them" or not.

@PaulMcKenzie thank you.  Follow up question: what is the proper to way initialize a pointer in a constructor?  my_pointer[0] = NULL; or *my_pointer = NULL:?

In your code, name[0] is not a pointer.  It is a single character.  The pointer has already been established when you used new[].  It is name that is a pointer, not name[0], thus you should not set it to NULL, since you've already set it to whatever new[] returned.  Also, your Software class is nothing more than the multiple String classes you will find over the internet and in several C++ books that were written prior to 1998.  If you did a search, you will find the code for these classes.

So would I just use name = new char in my Software class?
Also, I made the changes to the code to follow the rule of 3, but my class is still spitting out garbage.  [Edit] There are other member variables in the Software class that I didn't include.  I was trying to simplify my code to focus on the problem behavior and to save myself from the typing because I can't easily copy and paste the code from my NT 3.51 dev workstation.

Your operator= class leaks memory, as you did not delete[] the old allocation.   Second, as suggested previously, only write a String class.  Don't try and shoehorn an umpteen number of other things in the String class that has little to do with string handling.  The class should be able to create, copy, and return the string it is storing.
But to be honest, the comment section isn't meant to be a replacement for a C++ book.  There are multiple other issues with the code that would just be too much to go into.

Well I appreciate the feedback so far.  I have taken college level C++ courses, and I do own a few C++ books, and I feel my Google-fu is pretty adequate.  I come to SO when I'm stumped and need additional help.  But I understand what you are saying that this isn't the place for a back-and-forth discussion.  I was just hoping to learn more - and I've learned a few things, so thanks again for that.  Unfortunately, I still can't figure out my problem.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Various functions are using strncpy() to copy strings, but use strlen() to allocate strings.    The problem is that strncpy() does not guarantee the string being copied will be nul terminated, but strlen() relies on one being present.   So, if your class allocates/copies a string withot a nul terminator then later allocates/copies it again, the second allocate/copy has undefined behaviour.   Bear in mind, when dynamically allocating an array of char, a new expression does NOT initialise that array (so the +1 when allocating does not guarantee termination).

The assignment operator Software::operator= doesn't return anything. So the program has undefined behavior which means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely on the output of a program with UB. The program may just crash.

What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems

After trying to use the proposed custom string class and failing, I was able to get it to work by using void GetSoftware( Software**& software, const unsigned short ArraySize ).  I'm not quite sure why it works, but it seems that using the pass by reference operator & passes the class by reference, which allows the data to be retained on return from the function instead of going out of scope.
I now get a warning on the line calling the GetSoftware() function about a non-const reference bound to temporary during compile, but at least it works.
I will definitely keep in mind the points learned about pointer safety and try to use these concepts going forward.
